# making a class's static-member a function (closure) does not work

Tags: php, lambda, functional-programming, php-7

(PHP7)
Consider the following code, which tries to assign a function to a variable, and then make sure it is called only once.

```
class a{
  static public $b;
  static public function init(){
     self::$b();
     self::$b=function(){};
  }
}
a::$b=function(){echo 'Here I do very heavy stuff, but will happen only in the first time I call init()';};

for($i=0;$i<1000;$i++){
   a::init();
}
```

In php7 it will give an error that it expects `a::$b` to be a string (the function name to call).
If I use pure variables and not static members, it will work.
My question, is this suppose to work, or not, or is there  a small tweak I can do for this to work **without pure vars**?

Comment: This code wouldn't work whether in PHP 5 or PHP 7 though.

Comment: yes, I know, but shouldn't it? (i.e. a bug or a feature request?)

Comment: It's not a bug. It never worked in PHP 5. It __will__ work in PHP 7 when you use uniform variable syntax properly. i.e. `(self::$b)()`

Comment: This is probably the one thing about uniform variable syntax that _won't_ be backwards compatible with PHP 5 unfortunately.

Comment: I am done with php5 in  two weeks :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use PHP 7 [Uniform Variable Syntax](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax):

```
(self::$b)();
```

Or a temporary variable in PHP 5+ (including 7):

```
$init = self::$b;
$init();
```

[As seen on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/T5J8m).

Comment: I did solve this with temporary vars. that works fine. I think I will do the uniform syntax though, looks cleaner.